# writing ethernet driver, without building kernel?

Tags: linux, drivers

I write ethernet driver. But in order to test the driver, I need to make the kernel call the probe callback routine.

It seems that I must register it in the appropriate board file(no device tree in this version), in order to make the probe called. The thing is that if I change the board file, it requires me to build the whole kernel, and that takes 2 hours (!) in my virtual machine. I worked before that much smaller kernel/filesystems and it never took me such long time to build the kernel.

Is there any way to make this task more effecient ? for example, can I simulate inside driver that the device exist in the board ? Does it makes sense that kernel build takes ~2 hours in the virtual machine ?

Any idea will help, even upgraing the kernel or replacing host pc.

Thanks, Ran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build your driver as module, and configuring the kernel so that you can force unloading modules.

So when you change the driver, the kernel will recompile only the driver (and you don't need to install the new kernel, just to load the module from kernel sources.